# example of a sequence which is equivalent to zero at infinity but does not converge to zero

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to know if there is an example of sequence $(u_n)$ which is equivalent to zero at infinity but does not converge to zero?
$$
\exists ? (u_n) \;|\; u_n \sim 0 \mbox{ but }u_n\nrightarrow 0.
$$
If not, and if we consider this example:
$$
u_n=(n+1)^{\frac 1 3}-n^{\frac{1}{3}},
$$
we have $n+1\sim n$ at $\infty$ so that $u_n\sim 0$ at $\infty$ but can we deduce from this that the sequence $u_n$ converges to $0$ at $\infty$?

Comment: What does "being equivalent to zero at infinity" mean? What's your definition of this?

Comment: Let $(u_n)_n$ and $(v_n)_n$ be to sequences. $u_n\sim v_n$ at $\infty$ if $\lim_{n\goes +\infty}\frac{u_n}{v_n}=1$

Comment: But then a sequence $\;\{u_n\}\;$ is equivalent with zero at infinity means $\;\lim\frac{u_n}0=1\;$ ? This doesn't seem to make sense: what am I missing here?

Comment: As for the second part: consider $v_n := n + 1 -n = 1$, then similarly $n + 1 \sim n$, but the sequence certainly does not converge to $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalence relation $a_n\sim b_n$ defined by $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=1$ only makes sense when $b_n$ is zero only for finitely many terms, and is an equivalence relation only when both $a_n$ and $b_n$ are zero only finitely many times. Applying the definition out of this range yields a non-symmetric relation. We have $u_n\sim 0\iff \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_n}0=1$ which is false for every sequence $u_n$, even $u_n=0$, because the sequence we are taking a limit of has no defined terms. On the other hand, $0\sim u_n\iff\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac0{u_n}=1$ is false for every sequence $u_n$ (that is eventually nonzero) because every term is equal to zero.

Thus both $u_n\sim 0$ and $0\sim u_n$ are false for any sequence $u_n$, and so no sequence satisfies your requirement, even ignoring the "nonconvergent to zero" requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think "equivalence to zero " is better to be defined as : $x_n$ is said to be equivalent to zero at infinity if there exists some sequence $y_n$ converging to zero such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x_n}{y_n}=1$. with this definition such a sequence does not exist. Because if there exists some sequence $x_n$ converging to $a\neq 0$ then either $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x_n}{y_n}=+\infty$ or $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x_n}{y_n}=-\infty$ depending on $a$ to be positive or negative.

Comment: Your definition of "equivalent to zero" is just the same thing as "convergent to zero" by the limit rule for products.